Center the word "Appendix" and make it bigger
Is there some way to make the word "Appendix" bigger, so that it covers the page in the center, instead of a small "Appendix" in the upper left corner?
I use this code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\newcommand{\addappendix}{   % Self-created command to insert appendix with predefined settings
    \newpage
    \appendix
    \section*{Appendix}   % Name of appendix
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}  % Add appendix name to table of contents
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}    % Change numbering of section to upper-case letters.
\counterwithin{figure}{subsection}
    \counterwithin{table}{subsection}
}
\begin{document}


\addappendix


\newpage





\import{./Appendix/}{Triple tube}


\end{document}

I tried some formatting, but they all turn out with the appedixes being numbered with .1, .2 ... and the figures becoming .1,.2 ... instad of A, B and Figure A.1, A.2
My output is this:

but I would like it to be like this: 

Assuming you only have a single (unnumberted) appendicx, it would be easier to not use \section* or \part*.  \centerline{\huge\textbf{\appendixname}} and add some space above and below.

Actually, the \appendix command doesn't do much, so it is safe to redefine it. I'd actually recommend you to make Appendix look like \part (as well as in the TOC). For this, I referenced the \part definition of the book class (however, I disregarded the handling of twocolumn, twoside and openright options as well as settings to secnumdepth).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\appendix}{
    % "Copied" from the \appendix command
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \setcounter{subsection}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

    \counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \counterwithin{table}{section}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\appendixname} % Format appendix in TOC like \part

    % Inspired from \part in book class
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    {\centering
     \normalfont\Huge
     \textbf{\appendixname}\par}
    \vfill\newpage
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\appendix

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Edit: It is more correct to use \appendixname instead of the explicit Appendix to allow for language localisation.

Edit 2: The problem OP described in the comments is a common problem with hyperref (which OP initially didn't asked for). This is solved by adding \phantomsection right before \addcontentsline.

Thank you! I did some minor tweaking (changed section to subsection), as i wanted the different appendixes (A, B, C...) to be related to subsections, but this was a major help!
I do however have a minor problem. When i click on Appendix in the table of contents, I find myself at References. Any suggestions?

@EirikNordland I've added a solution to your new question. As a small tip: next time, please post a new question as this is actually unrelated to your initial one.
